# Jquery/Ajax request pending infintiley long and crash the apache

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi im new here an i got a problem with my code. I wanna check the status of a micro and change it via php and websockets. My ajax request works, but my first request after changing the status is pending infinitely long every time and crash my xampp apache. 
First of all, i check the status with my ajax request. Everything is fine. After pressing my button to change the status, the request will stuck and the setInterval will start the next request after 2 sec. Switching the status some more times will crash the apache now. If i delete the setInterval, the request will stuck also.

The html-jquery-code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>       
        <title>Mikrofone</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>check_status(); 
            var hash = "882c2071d8ce7ea8912929bbea384d2d2e653bf9";
            $(document).ready(function () {    
                check_status();                    
                setInterval('check_status()', 2000);
            });
            
            function check_status(){    
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: 'http://localhost/neuanfang/mikro.php',
                    data: {action: hash},
                    type: 'post',
                    //async: false,
                    success:function(output) {
                        console.log(output);
                        if (output=="Access denied"){
                            alert("Wrong Key");
                        }
                        else if (output==1){
                            var head = "Device is Unmuted";
                            var link = '<form action="mikro.html" method="post"><input onclick="mute()" value="Status Update" type="image" src="Icon_GREEN.png" /></form>';
                        }
                        else if (output!=1){
                            var head = "Device is Muted";
                            var link = '<form action="mikro.html" method="post"><input onclick="unmute()" value="Status Update" type="image" src="Icon_RED.png" /></form>';
                        }
                        $("#HEADER").html(head);
                        $("#SYMBOL").html(link);                                                   
                    }
                });
            }
        
            function unmute(){
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: 'http://localhost/neuanfang/mikro.php',
                    data: { unmute: hash},
                    type: 'post',
                    success:function(output) {                                              
                    }
                });
            }
        
            function mute(){
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: 'http://localhost/neuanfang/mikro.php',
                    data: { mute: hash},
                    type: 'post',
                    success:function(output) {            
                    }
                });
            }                    
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <th>
                <div id="HEADER"></div>
            </th>
        </table>
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="SYMBOL"></div>
                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="http://localhost/neuanfang/mikro.html" onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','width=440px,height=570px');
                        return false;"> <p style="text-align:center">Popup-Window</p></a>
                    </td>         
                </tr>
         </table>   
    </body>
</html>
```

The php-code:

```html
<?php
# enable sockets in php.ini
# extension=php_sockets.dll

ini_set('display_errors', 10);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 10);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

set_time_limit(2000);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 2000);

ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();

#echo 'creating socket...';
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === FALSE) {
    die('Error creating socket.');
}

#echo 'connecting microphone...';
$result = socket_connect($socket, '192.168.212.2', 2202);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('Error connecting microphone.');
}

function entry(){
 $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
 $result = socket_connect($socket, '192.168.212.2', 2202);
 $cmd = '< GET DEVICE_AUDIO_MUTE >';
 socket_write($socket, $cmd, strlen($cmd));
 while (($out = socket_read($socket, 2048, PHP_BINARY_READ)) !== FALSE) {
  if ($out === '< REP DEVICE_AUDIO_MUTE ON >'){
   echo 0;
  }
  if ($out === '< REP DEVICE_AUDIO_MUTE OFF >'){
   echo 1;
  }
  if (substr($out, -1) === '>') break;
 } 
}

function mute(){
 $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
 $result = socket_connect($socket, '192.168.212.2', 2202);
 $cmd = '< SET DEVICE_AUDIO_MUTE ON >';
 socket_write($socket, $cmd, strlen($cmd)); 
 while (($out = socket_read($socket, 2048, PHP_BINARY_READ)) !== FALSE) {  
  if (substr($out, -1) === '>') break;
 }
}

function unmute(){
 $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
 $result = socket_connect($socket, '192.168.212.2', 2202);
 $cmd = '< SET DEVICE_AUDIO_MUTE OFF >';
 socket_write($socket, $cmd, strlen($cmd));
 while (($out = socket_read($socket, 2048, PHP_BINARY_READ)) !== FALSE) { 
  if (substr($out, -1) === '>') break;
 } 
}

function check($post){
 $key= array(
  '882c2071d8ce7ea8912929bbea384d2d2e653bf9'
 ); 
 if (!in_array($post,$key)) {
  die('Access denied');
 }
}

if(isset($_POST['unmute']) && !empty($_POST['unmute'])) { 
 $post=$_POST['unmute'];
 check($post);
 unmute();   
}

if(isset($_POST['mute']) && !empty($_POST['mute'])) { 
 $post=$_POST['mute'];
 check($post);
 mute();   
}

if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
 $post=$_POST['action'];
 check($post);
 entry();   
}

socket_close($socket);
?>
```

[Browser-Consol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6TLS.png)

Comment: What this line`setInterval('check_status()', 2000);` suppose to do?

Comment: You don't need to use both `isset()` and `!empty()`. `empty()` performs its own `isset()` check first.

Comment: execute the function check_status ever 2 sec. This should check if i have the right hash, and create a websocket in my php file. This socket will check the status and return the status via 1 or 0.

Comment: My guess is that the `while` loops in `mute()` and `unmute()` aren't ending.